# Rolling drag and action-reaction forces

Tags: rotational-dynamics, terminology, friction

I do not understand the two factors acting on the car during driving, they are Rolling drag which it is [rolling resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) and action-reaction forces. If the Rolling friction reduces the the car kinetic energy, how the the reaction force produced to pulls car forward.

Comment: It is called an engine.

Comment: Are you asking, in effect, how do the car's tyres, under engine power, cause it to move foward?